# What is rollback?

Tags: discussion

I was reading through the badge descriptions and was wondering what the Cleanup badge was for. It says "First rollback", but what does rollback mean here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone edits one of your questions or answers, and you don't like the changes, you can revert the content to the original.  That.